# Getting the url's of links of website when clicked from google search in C# web browser control

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have used a web browser control in Visual studio 2010,
Now when I open google.com and search for any information it gives me lots of links.
When I click any of these links, I want the URL of the link so that I can compare it with my database.
I am rather a newbie in C#, so any type of help would be much appreciated.
I am from past 3 days after this and cant really get a solution so far.
I have tried navigating function but nothing happens, I also used link_clicked function even that seems to not work.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem a few days later.
What i did was when I open google.com and search for any information and click on the link
using the getUrl function I was fetching the url of the website i clicked on in the webbrowser_navigating function is C#. after getting this url I stored that in a variable and compared it with my database.